# How can I use AirPlay to watch on the television, but audio through my headphones?

Tags: iphone, audio, appletv, headphones, airplay

I have been using Netflix (for example) on my phone with headphones, but then I realized I would have a better experience watching it on the TV, but keep the audio on the phone.

Is there any way to project a video (only) onto the Apple TV, and keep the audio on my iPad/iPhone/Mac?

... I'll contrast this with OS X, where I'm able to airplay and switch between headphones and TV speakers just by plugging in headphones.

In addition there is this Midi control panel where I can configure outputs:

[image]

Comment: Are the headphones Bluetooth or wired?

Comment: They are wired - @owlswipe

Comment: Can you please provide more details in your question. Specifically, what model of Apple TV, iPhone, iPad and Mac do you have? And what versions of iOS and macOS are you running? Also, what is the model of your actual TV and what other equipment do you have (e.g. AV Receiver, etc) connected to your TV. Finally, is your Apple TV connected directly to your TV or is it connected via another device (e.g. AV Receiver) to your TV?

Comment: I have: MacBookPro 2013, iPad mini (latest-2016, Sierra), iPhone7, AppleTv 4.  The TV and AV system will be leaving soon (roommates moving out).  Latest iOS on everything @Monomeeth

Comment: @LamonteCristo I have a new solution for you in my answer below, let me know if it works or if you need any more help!

Comment: Hey there @LamonteCristo, you've gotten two great-looking answers below, do you mind accepting one of them or leaving a comment why not?

Answer (score 4):

This cannot be done natively from an iOS device as there are no output settings built in to the iOS platform that allow the splitting of the audio from the video while streaming a file. With the use of extra hardware and/or 3rd party software though what you're trying to accomplish can *technically* be done in a round-about way, just not the exact way you're describing, where your headphones would be connected to your phone.

This link has some options (some fairly cheap) that you could explore though:
[Use Headphones with Apple TV](http://www.appledystopia.com/how-to/use-headphones-with-apple-tv-page-2/).

I did notice you mentioned owning a Mac though. One option not mentioned in that article (because it's not Apple TV related) would be to just use your Mac connected to your tv, using a long HDMI cable and a 'Mini display port to HDMI adapter' ($10 on Amazon). That way you could sit with your Mac beside you and your headphones plugged into it, although you would have that HDMI cable strung across the room while in use that you would have to be careful of. (And you would have to remember to select your headphones from 'System Preferences > Sound > Output' likely every time you go to use it this way.)

Answer (score 4):

While you cannot AirPlay video and get audio through wired headphones, you [*can* connect Bluetooth headphones to an Apple TV 4th Generation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205302). Since you have wired headphones, you'll need to make them wireless, which you can do with a simple Bluetooth audio receiver like [this $15 one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013QJ0W8Q). Then, you can pair that Bluetooth audio receiver to your Apple TV, plug your headphones into the Bluetooth receiver, and be good to go.

I have no affiliation with the makers of the Bluetooth receiver, but I have tested it personally (playing music from iPhone to wired Beats wirelessly) and it works great.

[image]

Comment: While this is true, at present MFI headphone support on 4th gen ATV's is poor as only some of the "iOS Certified" headphones will work and there is no way to control their volume without independent controls on the headphones.

Answer (score 0):

had a similar issue, wanted to run audio through a karaoke speaker, and have airplay on the tv, it all worked until i installed youtube app, (it’s the kids ipad so normally no youtube) then the thing would either tell me it is connected to another device and disengage bluetooth or not mirror and play over bluetooth , i deleted my youtube app and used youtube on safari and all good.

hope this helps