# How to play audio in Safe Boot?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio, startup, catalina

I am [having an issue recently](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/378636/150109) which causes my MacBook Pro 2015, 15", to spontaneously (and randomly?) shut down.

These shut downs do not happen in Recovery Mode or Safe Boot.

Temporarily, before I am able to identify and fix the root cause, I would like to continue using my laptop.

I am actually very happy using Safe Boot for now, I can do almost everything I want to do.

However, I can't figure out how to enable audio output while in Safe Boot mode.

I know it's not really intended, so possible workarounds may be awkward, but how can I hear the sound output from my MacBook while it is in Safe Boot?

The only external speakers I have access to are my iPhone 7's (iOS 13.3) and lots of pairs of headphones (although idk if those count as "external speakers"). I added this information because I wonder if it's possible to stream the sound output through my iPhone perhaps (network connectivity seems to work fine while in Safe Boot), if it is indeed impossible to play audio on the MacBook while in Safe Boot.

Comment: afaik, Mac doesn't have a 'selective boot' option like Windows, so forget it until you can get the machine repaired.

Comment: "Some audio input or output devices might not work." See if you can use Audio Midi to channel some audio out https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262 ← Safe mode support article

Comment: @ankii the audio output devices which won't work are the: Internal Speakers, and Headphones (when connected). They don't even show up in System Preferences > Sound. These are the audio output devices I would like to get to work, and the only way I know of outputting audio from a MacBook (without e.g. a bluetooth speaker).

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/can-i-play-audio-from-my-iphone-on-my-mac/192910#192910 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277085/midi-in-audio-out-on-iphone-7 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/269266/how-can-i-use-airplay-to-watch-on-the-television-but-audio-through-my-headphone

Comment: There's probably little or no coreaudio support at all in safe mode. It is, by definition, a minimal OS with just enough to troubleshoot. Listening to the radio is not high on the list of priorities at that point.

Answer (score -2):

I have the exact same problem with my 15" mid-2010 MacBook Pro.  It does not suddenly reboot when in Safe Boot-- only in the normal boot.  Apple is aware of this problem but will not assign even one engineer to look into this problem as I have been complaining to them for over 6 years about this.

I was told that possibly the battery needs to be changed-  but Apple stopped making batteries for this model years ago.

Comment: Apple aren't going to spend time fixing a problem on a 10 year old Mac that they don't sell anymore. You can get third-party batteries. They are a bit of a lottery, but they're your only hope for vintage equipment.